# sequelize associations and api routes. unable to retrieve information from db

Tags: javascript, express, server, sequelize.js

I am really new to sequelize and express and I have been stuck for many hours already trying to wrap my head around the associations that I want to have in my database and how to retrieve information from my database. I have created a boarders-boards (as in surfboards... and riders) database. I have three main models on it: Boards, Riders, and Makers. 
- A maker has many boards and a board can only belong to a maker. I don't think I have any problem with this association. 
-  A rider can have many boards and a board can belong to many riders.

When populating my database, I have a RiderBoards table with riderId and boardsId... no problem up to there...

Sometimes, when starting my server I get an OID error but then it disappears...

NOW, In my api/riders route, I am trying to retrieve an array with all my rider objects in it using the "findAll()" method. It doesn't give me anything besides an empty array. Is this a problem with my database or associations? Is it a problem with my api route? IS it a problem connecting to my database? How can I get to retrieve what I want? I would really appreciate some guidance on this.

this is my api/riders route :

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const { Rider } = require('../database/index');

router.get(
  '/',
  asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const allRiders = await Rider.findAll();
    if(allRiders.length === 0){
      console.log(allRiders);
      res.json('No Riders found')
    }else{
      console.log(allRiders);
      res.json({allRiders});
    }
    /* etc */
  })
);
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  /* etc */
});
router.put('/:puppyId', function (req, res, next) {
  /* etc */
});
router.delete('/:puppyId', function (req, res, next) {
  /* etc */
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is my index to my db models:

```
"use strict";

const db = require("./db");
const Board = require("./board");
const Rider = require("./rider");
const Maker = require("./maker");

// Assosiations go here
Maker.hasMany(Board);
// Rider.hasMany(Board);
Board.belongsTo(Maker);
Board.belongsToMany(Rider,{through: 'RiderBoards'});
Rider.belongsToMany(Board,{through:'RiderBoards'});

module.exports = {
  db,
  Board,
  Rider,
  Maker
};
```

this is my index on the server side :

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session"); // sessions allow us to keep user autheticated even after refreshing their browser window
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require("path");
const apiRoutes = require("./api");
const db = require("./database/db");
const passport = require("passport");

const SequelizeStore = require("connect-session-sequelize")(session.Store);
const dbStore = new SequelizeStore({ db: db });

dbStore.sync();

//logging middleware

app.use(morgan("dev"));

//static middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // The “extended” syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format

app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || "Some insecurely saved secret", // the process.env.SESSION_SECRET allows us to use the secret from the enviroment variable instead of exposing our own secret
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: dbStore
    // duration: -> how long willthe session be alive for
    // activeDuration: INT -> before logging an user out, it allows INT extra time if require by the user
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize()); // We initilize passport so that it will consume our req.session object, and attach the user to the request object.
app.use(passport.session());

app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/index.html"));
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(err.stack);
  res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message || "internal server error.");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Thanks for any help/ guidance in this!

Comment: I am sure you would have checked that you have entries into the database. When this happened to me, I was looking in the wrong database because of the node_env. You can `create` an object and then `findAll` on it. Something like this `Rider.create({...}).then(() => {Rider.findAll()...`

Comment: I think my problem was that I was forcing true every time! thanks for answering @AbhinavD!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was happening: I was forcing **true** every time my database was sync-ing! Changing it to true kept my records in my database and so there were actual records to pull put when my query was hit.